# How to compose streams\Observables correctly

Tags: java, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have conceptual problem understanding how to compose between streams\Observables which have different return type.

Here is a draft method I'm trying to code:

```
public void findSeat() {
    rx.Observable<GameObject> userObs = context.getUser();
    rx.Observable<ActiveGame> gameObs = context.findGame();

    rx.Observable.zip(userObs, gameObs, (userObj, game) -> {

        User user = ...;

        final List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>(3); 

        if(userObj.getStatus() != ErrorCodes.STATUS_OK) {
            results.add(-1);
            return results;
        }

        ...
        ...

        //***********************************
        // THE PROBLEM IS HERE: 
        // "context.getActiveGameManager().updateGame(game)" returns Observable<GameOBject> and not List<Object> like .zip() expects.
        // because of that I cannot do:
        // "return context.getActiveGameManager().updateGame(game);"
        // How can I do this convertion from Observable<GameObject> to List<Object>
        //************************************

        context.getActiveGameManager().updateGame(game)
            .map((gameObj) -> {

                if(gameObj.getStatus() != ErrorCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                    results.add(-2);
                    return (Observable<? extends Object>) results;
                }

                results.add(ErrorCodes.STATUS_OK);
                results.add(user);
                results.add(gameObj);
                return gameObs;
        });

        return Observable.empty();

    }).subscribe((results) -> {

        int status = (int) results.get(0);
        User user = (User) results.get(1);
        ActiveGame game = (ActiveGame) results.get(2);


        replyObj.reply(new JsonObject()
                    .putString("action", CommandActions.FIND_SEAT)
                    .putNumber("status", status);
                    .putNumber("game_id", game.getGameId())
                );

    });
}
```

The flow is as follow:
1. emit 2 Observable using .zip method.
2. do some logic on the return value of streams and if it results in error-code --> put it in list and return it so "subscribe" can return the error to user.
3. if no error, emit another "update" method using flatMap() - and this is where I have my problem.
4. eventually, all the results should be processed in "subscribe" because this is the point I acknowledge the user about his request.

Hope it's clear enough...

by the way, I'm trying to learn rxJava, but it's very hard I find there are enough\good sources - can someone recommend to me the best way to learn it?? I trying looking at tutorials at Youtube, Wikipedia, Github...most of them teaches using Scala and other scripting languages - couldn't find anything in Java.

Thank you for everyone that put the effort trying understand it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were almost there, but try breaking down the code inside your .zip lambda into smaller Rx operations. For example:

```
rx.Observable
    .zip(userObs, gameObs, (userObj, game) -> {
        // Combine the user & game objects and pass them to the
        // next Rx operation.
        return new UserAndActiveGame(userObj, game);
    })
    .filter(userAndActiveGame -> {
        // Remove this filter if you want errors to make it to the subscriber.
        return userAndActiveGame.getUserObj().getStatus() == ErrorCodes.STATUS_OK;
    })
    .flatMap(userAndActiveGame -> {
        // Remove this check if you filter errors above.
        if (userAndActiveGame.getUserObj().getStatus() != ErrorCodes.STATUS_OK) {
            return Observable.just(new FindSeatResult(-1));
        }

        return context.getActiveGameManager().updateGame(userAndActiveGame.getGame())
            .map(gameObj -> {
                if (gameObj.getStatus() != ErrorCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                    return new FindSeatResult(-2);
                }

                User user =...; // Whatever you are doing to get this in your example code.
                return new FindSeatResult(ErrorCodes.STATUS_OK, user, gameObj);
            });
    })
```

The following classes are used for passing intermediate and final results:

```
private class UserAndActiveGame {
    private final GameObject userObj;
    private final ActiveGame game;

    public UserAndActiveGame(GameObject userObj, ActiveGame game) {
        this.userObj = userObj;
        this.game = game;
    }

    public GameObject getUserObj() {
        return userObj;
    }

    public ActiveGame getGame() {
        return game;
    }
}

private class FindSeatResult {
    private final int status;
    private final User user;
    private final ActiveGame game;

    public FindSeatResult(int status) {
        this(status, null, null);
    }

    public FindSeatResult(int status, User user, ActiveGame game) {
        this.status = status;
        this.user = user;
        this.game = game;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public ActiveGame getGame() {
        return game;
    }
}
```

Your subscriber then uses the packaged result similar to what you are already doing.

```
.subscribe((results) -> {
    // You don't need this if you filter errors above.
    if (findSeatResult.getStatus() == -1) {
        return;
    }

    int status = findSeatResult.getStatus();
    User user = findSeatResult.getUser();
    ActiveGame game = findSeatResult.getGame();

    replyObj.reply(new JsonObject()
                .putString("action", CommandActions.FIND_SEAT)
                .putNumber("status", status);
                .putNumber("game_id", game.getGameId())
            );
});
```

By using the intermediate and final results classes instead of passing around your results in a `List<Object>` your code is much more forgiving to changes and the compiler will type check everything for you.

Comment: WOW - Thanks for answering - I'm reviewing your reply, basically trying to understand it. Thank you!!

Comment: because I had problems understanding how to do this, I was about to use nested .zip()'s ...but you solution looks perfect to me! Thank you.

Comment: regarding .filter, if the condition returns true --> continues to next phase, if 'false' --> than what?? it breaks the chain and that's it?? is there a way to make it go to 'subscribe' or 'error' method for sending reply to user.

Comment: Question: let's assume that it's more complicated than the above example, and I'm required to make more rx calls - so if i'm not mistaken than I need to make more "helper classes" for passing parameters from one rx call to the other - right?

Comment: For the filter, return true for any item you want to continue on. Returning false will discard the item. Since it sounds like you want the errors to continue on then you can remove the .filter operation completely.

Comment: If you need to .zip more observables together then you would need to add fields to the UserAndActiveGame class. If there are additional observables that depend on items emitted by userObs & gameObs then you will most likely add more .flatMap operations to the end that depend on those items.